# Mod-rewrite has revealed itself

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I thought that apache mod_rewrite would hide the URL that is being redirected to. i.e. if a user enters 
http://site.com/iPhone
and i've set it up to redirect to 
http://site.com/search.php?search=iPhone
I would have expected that
http://site.com/iPhone
would still be displayed in the address bar?

.htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^search/(.*) search.php?search=$1 [R]
</IfModule>
```

Have I got this completely confused?

Comment: Ugh, indecent exposure of mod_rewrite should be a crime. Put a bathrobe on it, or something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `[R]` modifier causes the response to be redirected to the new URL, rather than handled in-place. Ditch that, and it ought to work (any other problems notwithstanding).

*When I'm doing URL rewriting, I like to keep the [`mod_rewrite` cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/apache/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/) from Added Bytes (formerly ILoveJackDaniels) to hand.*